# What is the difference between 举行 and 举办?

Tags: meaning, difference

What is the difference between "举行" and "举办"? Both of them have the meaning of 'holding / organizing an event", but do they have any difference?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An answer I found on [Baidu Zhidao](http://zhidao.baidu.com/link?url=tKhYZuKNEya_MQ0EBcHvM67Bbm8-FLgjJ3WQ_MfmgefVLR0BPIgI_YsEYlcJwZLYTcGWVLgX8fQ9MeHQfNMPsK) says this:

> 二者的区别在字面上，“行”注重过程，“办”强调事情，进行（集会、比赛等）

The difference between the two words can be seen from the words themselves, “行” focuses on the process of events, while “办” emphases the thing things and the carrying out of such things themselves (meetings, competitions, etc).

The following all use "举行"

> ```
> ～会谈 
> ～球赛 
> 展览会在文化宫～。
> ```

```
Hold talks
to hold a sporting event
the exhibit will be held at the cultural palace
```

The following, here, would all use "举办"

> ```
> ～展览会
> ～学术讲座
> ～训练班
> ```

```
To hold an exhibition
The hold an academic speech
To hold a training class
```

---

So basically
行 = just doing it
办 = includes setting it up and doing it (edit: or organizing like you said in your original post)

Answer (score 1):

举办 applies to carnivals, Olympics, super bowl, exhibitions, ...

举行 applies to company meetings, wedding ceremonies, funerals, group discussions, ...

Comment: Didn't you say the opposite? Doesn't 举行 go with carnivals, olympics etc.?

Comment: @MrVocabulary 举办 refers to exciting, crowded events. 举行 refers to routine, non-exciting events. An example is that the latter can apply to funerals.

Comment: @MrVocabulary Of course, if you are talking about the wedding of Prince William, using 举办 is OK.

Comment: it seems based on user3306356's answer, that 举办 connects with events that are longer or last multiple days, while 举行 seems to concern single events. Would you use 举办 if Prince William's wedding was big (many participants) but short (let's say, 1 hour official celebration)?

Comment: @MrVocabulary If it takes a committee to run a event, one can use "举办" with it. Prince Wiliam's wedding definitely counts. An exception is that if it is the prince himself is talking about he wedding, and he doesn't want to boast about it, he should use "举行". While a reporter reporting on it will go with "举办".

Answer (score 0):

I would supplement the two other answers (although I think John Z. Li’s answer switched the examples) by stating that it seems that:

举办 describes single events, defined by one point in time (like an hour-long meeting, a single football match).

举行 describes long-lasting events, defined by multilple points in time (like a series of seminars, or weekly exhibition).